# Javascript: If POST response is OK, set a cell in google sheet with "Okay", else update "false"

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I am working on a task that picks the last updated row in google sheet and posts it to another system via external API.

On successful POST response, I would like a specific column in the google sheet to be set to true, else if it fails, it should set to false.

I am not sure how to go about this and will appreciate assistance here. Here is the first part of the code that posts to external API

```
function lastRowData(){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
 var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow() 
 var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn()
 var lastRowData = sheet.getRange(lastRow,1,1,lastCol).getValues()
 return lastRowData[0]
}
function myFunction() {
var lastRow = lastRowData()
var data = {

    'name':lastRow[2],
    'client': lastRow[3],
    'starts_at':lastRow[5],
    'ends_at':lastRow[6],
    'project_state':lastRow[4],
};
var payload = JSON.stringify(data);
var options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
    'payload' : data,
};
var url = 'https://api.10000ft.com/api/v1/projects?auth=token';
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response);
 return response.getContentText();
}
```

Ideally something like:

```
  if (response.ok){
    activesheet.getRange(lastRow,1,1,lastCol).setvalue("true")
    } else {
      activesheet.getRange(lastRow,1,1,lastCol).setvalue("false")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [HTTPResponse.getResponseCode()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response.html?hl=en#getResponseCode())

```
function getLastRowData(sheet) {

    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
    var lastRowData = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, lastCol).getValues();

    return {data: lastRowData[0], row: lastRow};
}

function myFunction() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

    var lastRowData = getLastRowData(sheet);
    var lastRow = lastRowData.row;

    var data = lastRowData.data;

    var data = {

        'name': data[2],
        'client': data[3],
        'starts_at': data[5],
        'ends_at': data[6],
        'project_state': data[4],
    };
    var payload = JSON.stringify(data);

    var options = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'payload': payload,
        'muteHttpExceptions': true
    };
    var url = 'https://api.10000ft.com/api/v1/projects?auth=token';
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

    if (response.getResponseCode() === 200) { //or whatever you think will work, 200, 201...
        sheet.getRange('K' + lastRow).setValue("true");
    }
    else {
        sheet.getRange('K' + lastRow).setValue("false");
    }
}
```

And if you are only setting value for 1 cell, you can use the [Sheet.getRange(row, num)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer)) version (with 2 params)

Comment: Many thanks for the pointer. I have added the code you suggested and get error during execution    **ReferenceError: "activesheet" is not defined**

Comment: Sorry. I have edited to add the sheet instead of activeSheet variable. I had copied it from your snippet. You might need to change the  ..getRange(row, col) if you are looking to change multiple cells.

Comment: @Wilber Apologies again. this might still not work because the lastRow, lastCol are unavailable. Which cell are you looking to update ?

Comment: Thanks for getting back.  I am looking to update a specific cell at the end of the copied row say cell **K2** should have **true** or **false** value after the row has been copied.  This should happen every time a row is copied. say the next row is copied, the true or false value should reflect in **K3**

Comment: I have added the new code. You should be able to replace all the code with this. Assuming that the row you are getting the data from needs its col K updated: ...sheet.getRange('K' + lastRow) should work.

Comment: Thanks, @Karan, This works up to the authentication where an error is thrown *Request failed for https://api.10000ft.com returned code 403. Truncated server response:* sorry for bothering you with all these questions but am pretty new to Javascript, so will appreciate any useful leads

Comment: Looks like you need an auth token or key for using the API. Do you have any ? If not then I'm afraid it might be a bit complex to be discussed here because of requiring understanding of some Auth concepts.
Also I added  'muteHttpExceptions': true to the options so it will not throw error but you will always get false in the cell.

Comment: This is really helpfull @Karan. To answer your question, yes I do have the auth token. I have also added muteHttpExceptions to the code and truncated response error is now gone. I have one last challenge and that is **TypeError: Cannot find function setvalue in object Range** for line **sheet.getRange('K' + lastRow).setvalue("false");**. Have any idea of a work around?

Comment: @Wilber New questions should be asked in a new post. If the answer provided satisfied the question asked above, accept the answer and ask a new question. You cannot chain related questions in comments. Read stack overflow code of conduct and [ask]. Having said that, it appears to be a typo: `setValue()` not `setvalue()`. Note the case.

Comment: @Wilber I'm sorry again. I copied the setValue code from your snippet. It should be setValue instead of setvalue (case sensitive)

Comment: setValue() typo on case sensitivity could have been the issue.